# uvcvideo: Non-zero status (-5) in status completion handler

Tags: usb, pi-2, driver, opencv, webcam

I'm using a RPI2 and a USB webcam (Microsoft HD3000) to record video.

Now, I'm doing extensive testing and I see that when I record long video (10-12 hours) I sometimes see an error in dmesg.

```
uvcvideo: Non-zero status (-5) in status completion handler.
```

After this error, my camera is not working anymore. I have to restart my program to fix the error.

My program is using OpenCV 2.4.1 or 2.4.11 (I tried both). I'm using cvQueryFrame() to get the pictures and cvCreateVideoWriter()/cvWriteFrame() to record the video to a USB dongle (32 GB).

I also tried to enable some uvcvideo driver options but I still have the problem after a few hours.

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/uvcvideo.conf
options uvcvideo nodrop=1
options uvcvideo timeout=5000
options uvcvideo quirks=0x80
```

Any idea what could cause the problem ?

What would be the best way to catch the problem and deal with it ?

Comment: As per the first comment to the [answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/56166/19334) the problem has "gone away" and thus there can't be reproduced. I don't know what flag to use in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot answer what the problem is, but have a simpler setup with exactly the same error message. I am using Pi Zero to stream cheap USB webcam 320x240 video to connected LCD:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1045564#p1045564

The gstreamer command is this:

```
pi@raspberrypi02:~ $ gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240, framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! fbdevsink device=/dev/fb1
```

The error message can be seen via "dmesg" after display went black:

```
[  975.037445] uvcvideo: Non-zero status (-5) in status completion handler.
```

So this time problem occured after 16 minutes, that is the typical time, although the camera did work >2h sometimes.

> After this error, my camera is not working anymore. 
>   I have to restart my program to fix the error.

Restarting gstreamer command alone does not help. I have to "sudo rmmod" modules fbtft_device, fb_ili9341 and then fbtft in that order, and start framebuffer again via:

```
sudo modprobe fbtft_device name=rpi-display gpios=reset:23,dc:24,led:18 rotate=90
```

So it is the framebuffer module that seems to be responsible as in your case.

Hermann.

Comment: I upgraded to Raspbian (2016-05-27). That is Kernel: Linux rpi 4.4.11-v7+ #888 SMP Mon May 23 20:10:33 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux. I'm also now using OpenCV 3.1 with C++ API. The problem does not occurs anymore. I compiled OpenCV from source by following this procedure: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/